# Как отсортировать PHP массив?

Tags: php

Всем привет!

Есть массив вид:

```
$array = [
    array(
        0=>[0=> "date", 1=> "created_at", 2=> "warranty"],
        1=>[0=> "11111111111111", 1=> "22222222222", 2=> "rerererer"]
    ),
    array(
        0=>[0=> "created_at", 1=> "date", 2=> "warranty"],
        1=>[0=> "3333333", 1=> "44444444444444", 2=> "xzzxzxzxzx"]
    ),
    array(
        0=>[0=> "warranty", 1=> "created_at", 2=> "date"],
        1=>[0=> "55555555", 1=> "6666666", 2=> "nbnbnbnbnbn"]
    ),
];
```

Нужно привести его к виду:

```
$arRes = [
    array(
        0=>[0=> "date", 1=> "created_at", 2=> "warranty"],
        1=>[0=> "11111111111111", 1=> "22222222222", 2=> "rerererer"],
        2=>[0=> "44444444444444", 1=> "3333333", 2=> "xzzxzxzxzx"],
        3=>[0=> "nbnbnbnbnbn", 1=> "6666666", 2=> "55555555"],
    )
];
```

мне пока приходит в голову что то вроде:
[date]=>[0=>значение1, 1=>значение2...]
[created_at]=>[0=>значение1, 1=>значение2...]...

а потом уже придать ему необходимый вид

P.S. Расписывать весь код нет необходимости, нужно что бы мне просто объяснили логику реализации.

Comment: Во-первых это не только сортировка, во-вторых, у вас два ключа `2`, такого быть не может. К тому же, какие попытки решения проблемы вы предприняли?

Comment: Попробовал собрать массив вида 
[date]=>[0=>значение1, 1=>значение2...]
[created_at]=>[0=>значение1, 1=>значение2...]...
сравнивая ключи заголовков(date, created at..)с ключами значений(у заголовков и значений ключи всегда соотвествуют друг другу).
ключ поправил

Comment: Нажмите [edit] чтобы дополнить вопрос. Комментарии для других целей

Answer (score 0):

Только это у вас не сортировка. Это реструктуризация.

```
$keys = [];
$keyedSource = [];
foreach($source as $table){
  $keyedSource[] = array_combine($table[0], $table[1]);
  $keys = array_unique(array_merge($keys, $table[0]));
}
$result = [$keys];
foreach($keys as $keyIndex=>$key) foreach($keyedSource as $i=>$row){
  $result[$i + 1][$keyIndex] = $row[$key] ?? null;
}
//(не проверял код. может быть ошибка есть, но суть думаю понятна)
```

Если не учесть то, что ключей может быть переменное количество, или они могут не совпадать - было бы в 2 раза короче.

Только замечу - таблица в виде матрицы, с таким неудобно работать: без строковых ключей. Для вашей дальнейшей задачи, скорее всего массив удобнее всего было бы оставить в виде `$keyedSource` , при чём в качестве ключей самого массива `$keyedSource` присвоить id `$keyedSource = array_combine(array_column($keyedSource, 'id'), $keyedSource)` ( он же у вас наверняка есть в колонках ) - вот это будет уже наиболее удобная структура для работы с табличными данными.